# 1) Leia uma matriz 10 x 10 e escreva a localização (linha e a coluna) do maior valor

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, matriz

DESAFIO DA QUESTÃO 1 | Agora, não esqueça de informar qual é a posição deste maior valor.

Não consigo de forma alguma mostrar a posição do maior valor, a seguir, irei upar o código:

```
from random import randint

matriz_10x10 = []

for linha in range(10):
    linha = []

    for coluna in range(10):
        linha.append(randint(0, 10000))

    matriz_10x10.append(linha)

for linha_matriz in matriz_10x10:
    print(linha_matriz)
```

isso me retorna a seguinte lista:

```
[9084, 3990, 7211, 8670, 7057, 1310, 172, 6029, 7080, 2736]
[1039, 5584, 94, 428, 2429, 8719, 7838, 9331, 9274, 3163]
[166, 664, 5928, 656, 4576, 2585, 9654, 3071, 530, 9457]
[8563, 969, 9464, 2161, 3446, 718, 5524, 4919, 8249, 2624]
[2436, 1633, 1146, 2718, 4335, 5981, 772, 1345, 2126, 888]
[9860, 8196, 7874, 2661, 3504, 9538, 4872, 7993, 8629, 6598]
[8, 527, 5426, 4970, 8553, 5912, 2510, 396, 1304, 8640]
[4661, 1554, 4380, 2625, 6098, 4635, 9876, 503, 5484, 2131]
[8612, 1953, 2372, 6697, 4973, 7691, 8735, 4418, 7584, 3881]
[3561, 8265, 9219, 5248, 1018, 9481, 51, 8268, 3733, 9293]

maior_valor = 0

for linha in matriz_10x10:
    for coluna in linha:
        if maior_valor < coluna:
            maior_valor = coluna

print(maior_valor)

Retorna: 9876
```

Agora chega a parte que mostra a posição do valor 9876 na lista... Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Comment: Você precisa criar duas variáveis, linha e coluna, que atualizam sempre que o maior valor é encontrado.

Comment: Tentei fazer isso, mas sou iniciante no python, esses problemas foram passados para mim como desafio.

Pesquisei bastante, fiz diversas tentativas, mas sempre erro em algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única coisa que você precisa fazer é obter a posição do valor com o método `index` e depois armazená-la à uma variável.

Veja o exemplo abaixo onde eu crio uma tupla que armazena o maior valor e a sua posição.

```
element = (0, )

for line in matriz:
    for value in line:
        if element[0] < value:
            x = line.index(value)
            y = matriz.index(line)
            element = (value, y, x)
```

Você também pode utilizar o `range` na estrutura de repetição `for` para obter os índices sem precisar usar o método.

```
element = (0, )

for line in range(len(matriz)):
    for column in range(len(matriz[line])):

        value = matriz[line][column]

        if element[0] < value:
            element = (value, line, column)
```

Answer (score 1):

Como você quer tanto o maior elemento quanto sua posição, uma opção é usar [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), que permite iterar ao mesmo tempo pelos elementos e seus respectivos índices.

Aí basta guardar a posição sempre que for encontrado um maior elemento:

```
maior_valor = -1

for i, linha in enumerate(matriz_10x10):
    for j, coluna in enumerate(linha):
        if maior_valor < coluna:
            maior_valor = coluna
            posicao_maior = (i, j)

print(maior_valor)
print(posicao_maior)
```

Detalhe que o maior valor começa com um valor que seja menor que todos os valores possíveis da lista. Isso evita o raro - porém possível - caso em que todos os elementos são zero, pois se `maior_valor` começasse com zero, nunca entraria no `if` e a posição não seria setada (esse é um caso que a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/450079/112052) não tratou, já que ela inicia o maior com zero - mesmo sendo raro e pouco provável que todos os valores sejam zero, ainda é possível, e é melhor ter algo que funcione sempre, ainda mais se a solução for tão simples quanto mudar o valor inicial).

A outra solução com `index` é ruim porque `index` percorre a lista desde o início para encontrar o índice, o que além de ineficiente é desnecessário, já que você já está no meio de um *loop* percorrendo a lista, então para que percorrê-la novamente para procurar pelo índice se você já pode tê-lo diretamente usando `enumerate`? (ao percorrer várias vezes a mesma lista sem necessidade, você está usando o ["algoritmo" do *Shlemiel the painter*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/))

É claro que para listas pequenas, e rodando poucas vezes, a diferença será insignificante, mas é importante se atentar a estes detalhes. Em sistemas reais, com muitos dados e rodando várias vezes, coisas assim podem fazer toda a diferença.